# Automatically refreshing tableview with string array chosen from popover pickerview

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

I'm trying to get a tableview to update its rows when the user has tapped a button which brings up a picker viewer of available languages in a pop over controller, and the language is then changed.

I've tried to reload the tableview from the pop over controller's done button method. I've also tried to reload the tableview from the tableview's class' viewDidAppear() and viewWillAppear() methods. None of the above have had the desired effect.

```swift
import UIKit

class LanguagesPopOverController: UIViewController, UIPickerViewDelegate, UIPickerViewDataSource {

    //@IBOutlet var tableView: UITableView!
    @IBOutlet weak var picker: UIPickerView!
    @IBOutlet weak var done: UIButton!
    @IBOutlet weak var cancel: UIButton!
    var languages = [String]()
    var chosenLanguage = String()

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
        loadLanguages()

    //tableView.allowsMultipleSelection = false

        view.frame.size.height = 324

        picker.delegate = self
        picker.dataSource = self
        picker.reloadAllComponents()

        done.backgroundColor = .init(white: 0.95, alpha: 1.0)
        done.layer.cornerRadius = 5
        done.layer.borderWidth = 3
        done.layer.borderColor = UIColor.clear.cgColor
        cancel.backgroundColor = .init(white: 0.95, alpha: 1.0)
        cancel.layer.cornerRadius = 5
        cancel.layer.borderWidth = 3
        cancel.layer.borderColor = UIColor.clear.cgColor
    }

    // Number of columns of data
    func numberOfComponents(in picker: UIPickerView) -> Int {
        return 1
    }

    // The number of rows of data
    func pickerView(_ picker: UIPickerView, numberOfRowsInComponent component: Int) -> Int {
        print("Number of languages are: \(languages.count)")
        return languages.count
    }

    // The data to return for the row and component (column) that's being passed in
    func pickerView(_ picker: UIPickerView, titleForRow row: Int, forComponent component: Int) -> String? {
        return languages[row].capitalized
    }

    // Capture the picker view selection
    func pickerView(_ picker: UIPickerView, didSelectRow row: Int, inComponent component: Int) {
        // This method is triggered whenever the user makes a change to the picker selection.
        // The parameter named row and component represents what was selected.
        chosenLanguage = languages[row]
        print("chosenLanguage in pickerView in LanguagePickerViewController is: \(chosenLanguage)")
    }

    @IBAction func done(_ sender: Any) {
            chosenLanguageSave()
        let wordsVC = WordsViewController()
        wordsVC.chosenLanguage = self.chosenLanguage
        let languagesVC = LanguagesViewController()
        languagesVC.chosenLanguage = self.chosenLanguage
        let homeworkVC = HomeworkViewController()
        homeworkVC.chosenLanguage = self.chosenLanguage
        let testVC = TestViewController()
        testVC.chosenLanguage = self.chosenLanguage
        dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
    }

    @IBAction func cancel(_ sender: Any) {
        dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
    }

    func chosenLanguageSave() {
        if let defaults = UserDefaults(suiteName: "group.co.uk.tirnaelectronics.hyperpolyglot.todayview") {
            defaults.set(chosenLanguage, forKey: "languageChosen")
            print("chosenLanguage in chosenLanguageSave in LanguagesPopOverController is: \(chosenLanguage)")
        }
    }

    func loadLanguages() {
        if let defaults = UserDefaults(suiteName: "group.co.uk.tirnaelectronics.hyperpolyglot.todayview") {
            if var savedLanguages = defaults.object(forKey: "savedLanguages") as? [String] {
                print("savedLanguages in loadLanguages in LanguagesPopOverController are: \(savedLanguages)")
                languages.removeAll()
                languages = savedLanguages
                savedLanguages.removeAll()
                print("savedLanguages in loadLanguages in LanguagesPopOverController after removeAll: \(savedLanguages)")
                print("languages in loadLanguages in LanguagesPopOverController  are: \(languages)")
            }
        }
    }
}
```

WordsViewController:

```swift
import UIKit

class WordsViewController: UIViewController, UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource, UITabBarControllerDelegate, UIPopoverPresentationControllerDelegate {

    @IBOutlet weak var tableView: UITableView!
    @IBOutlet weak var clear: UIButton!
    @IBOutlet weak var reset: UIButton!
    @IBOutlet weak var sort: UIButton!
    @IBOutlet weak var languagePicker: UIButton!

    var words = [String]()
    var chosenLanguageWords = [String]()
    var chosenWords = [String]()
    var useHomework: Bool!
    var languages = [String]()
    var language = String()
    var chosenLanguage = String()
    var textField: UITextField?
    let wordString = "Words"

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        loadLanguages()
        chosenLanguageLoad()
        loadInitialValues()

        print("chosenLanguage in viewDidLoad in WordsViewController is: \(chosenLanguage)")
        //loadInitialValues()
        tableView.allowsMultipleSelection = false
        tableView.reloadData()

        navigationItem.title = "\(chosenLanguage.capitalized) Words"
        navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = UIBarButtonItem(barButtonSystemItem: .play, target: self, action: #selector(test))
        navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = UIBarButtonItem(barButtonSystemItem: .add, target: self, action: #selector(addNewWord))

        print("languages array is: \(languages)")

        clear.backgroundColor = .init(white: 0.95, alpha: 1.0)
        clear.layer.cornerRadius = 5
        clear.layer.borderWidth = 3
        clear.layer.borderColor = UIColor.clear.cgColor

        reset.backgroundColor = .init(white: 0.95, alpha: 1.0)
        reset.layer.cornerRadius = 5
        reset.layer.borderWidth = 3
        reset.layer.borderColor = UIColor.clear.cgColor
        reset.isEnabled = true

        sort.backgroundColor = .init(white: 0.95, alpha: 1.0)
        sort.layer.cornerRadius = 5
        sort.layer.borderWidth = 3
        sort.layer.borderColor = UIColor.clear.cgColor

        // Need to write in a check to see if words array is alphabetically ordered
        disableSort()

        //homeworkOrChosen.titleLabel?.text = "Chosen"
    }

    @IBAction func languagePicker(_ sender: UIButton) {

        //let chooseLanguageContent = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "LanguagePickerPopOver")
        //let chooseLanguageNav = UINavigationController(rootViewController: chooseLanguageContent!)
        //chooseLanguageContent?.modalPresentationStyle = UIModalPresentationStyle.popover

        //let languagePicker = chooseLanguageNav.popoverPresentationController
        //chooseLanguageContent?.preferredContentSize = CGSize(width: 100,height: 100)
        //languagePicker?.delegate = self
        //languagePicker?.sourceView = self.view
        //languagePicker?.sourceRect = CGRect(x: 100,y: 100,width: 300,height: 300)

        //self.present(chooseLanguageNav, animated: true, completion: nil)

        //let LPView = LanguagesPopOverController()
        //LPView.languages = self.languages
        //print("languages passed to LanguagePickerViewController are: \(LPView.languages)")
        //present(chooseLanguageContent!, animated: true, completion: nil)
    }

    override func shouldPerformSegue(withIdentifier EditWords: String, sender: Any?) -> Bool {
        return true
    }

    override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
        if let testVC = segue.destination as? TestViewController {
            testVC.useHomework = self.useHomework
        }
    }

    @IBAction func clear(_ sender: UIButton) {
        // create an alert to get user to confirm intentions
        let ac = UIAlertController(title: "Clear Words", message: "Are you sure you want to delete words?", preferredStyle: .alert)
        // add user actions, "OK" to confirm, and "Cancel" to abort
        ac.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Current Language", style: .default, handler: clearWords))
        ac.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "All Languages", style: .default, handler: clearAllWords))
        ac.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Cancel", style: .cancel))

        // present the alert controller to the user
        present(ac, animated: true)
    }

    func clearWords(action: UIAlertAction!) {
        words.removeAll()
        print("words in clearWords after removeAll in WordsViewController are: \(words)")
        chosenLanguageWords.removeAll()
        print("chosenLanguageWords in clearAll after removeAll in WordsViewController are: \(chosenLanguageWords)")
        saveWords()
        tableView.reloadData()
        disableSort()
    }

    func clearAllWords(action: UIAlertAction!) {
        clearWordsAllLanguages()
        disableSort()
    }

    func clearWordsAllLanguages() {
        if let defaults = UserDefaults(suiteName: "group.co.uk.tirnaelectronics.hyperpolyglot.todayview") {
            defaults.removeObject(forKey: "words")
            words.removeAll()
            print("words in clearWords after removeAll in WordsViewController are: \(words)")
            chosenLanguageWords.removeAll()
            print("chosenLanguageWords in clearAll after removeAll in WordsViewController are: \(chosenLanguageWords)")
            saveWords()
        }
        disableSort()
        tableView.reloadData()
    }

    @IBAction func reset(_ sender: UIButton) {
        // create an alert to get user to confirm intentions
        let ac = UIAlertController(title: "Reset Words", message: "Are you sure you want to delete all your created words, including homework, and use starter words?", preferredStyle: .alert)
        // add user actions, "OK" to confirm, and "Cancel" to abort
        ac.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "OK", style: .default, handler: resetWords))
        ac.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Cancel", style: .cancel))

        // present the alert controller to the user
        present(ac, animated: true)
    }

    func resetWords(action: UIAlertAction!) {
        if let defaults = UserDefaults(suiteName: "group.co.uk.tirnaelectronics.hyperpolyglot.todayview") {
            defaults.removeObject(forKey: "words")
            loadInitialValues()
            tableView.reloadData()
        }
    }

    @IBAction func sort(_ sender: UIButton) {
        words.sort()
        tableView.reloadData()
        disableSort()
    }

    func enableSort() {
        sort.isEnabled = true
        sort.alpha = 1
    }

    func disableSort() {
        sort.isEnabled = false
        sort.alpha = 0.25
    }

    func loadLanguages() {
        if let defaults = UserDefaults(suiteName: "group.co.uk.tirnaelectronics.hyperpolyglot.todayview") {
            if var savedLanguages = defaults.object(forKey: "savedLanguages") as? [String] {
                print("savedLanguages in loadLanguages in WordsViewController are: \(savedLanguages)")
                languages.removeAll()
                languages = savedLanguages
                savedLanguages.removeAll()
                print("savedLanguages in loadLanguages in WordsViewController after removeAll: \(savedLanguages)")
                print("languages in loadLanguages in WordsViewController  are: \(languages)")
            }
        }
    }

    @objc func test() {
        if chosenLanguageWords.isEmpty {
            let ac = UIAlertController(title: "Add Some Words!", message: nil, preferredStyle: .alert)
            let okAction = UIAlertAction(title: "OK", style: .default)
            ac.addAction(okAction)
            present(ac, animated: true)
        } else {
            useHomework = false
            self.performSegue(withIdentifier: "Test", sender: self)
        }
    }

    func chosenLanguageLoad() {
        if let defaults = UserDefaults(suiteName: "group.co.uk.tirnaelectronics.hyperpolyglot.todayview") {
            if let loadChosenLanguage = defaults.object(forKey: "languageChosen") as? String {
                chosenLanguage = loadChosenLanguage
                print("Chosen language in chosenLanguageLoad in WordsViewController is: \(chosenLanguage)")
            }
        }
    }

    @objc func loadInitialValues() {
        words.removeAll()
        if let defaults = UserDefaults(suiteName: "group.co.uk.tirnaelectronics.hyperpolyglot.todayview") {
            print("words in loadInitialValues in WordsViewController after clear all: \(words)")
            print("chosenLanguage in loadInitialValues in WordsViewController is: \(chosenLanguage)")
            if var savedWords = defaults.object(forKey: "words") as? [String] {
                print("savedWords in loadInitialValues in WordsViewController are: \(savedWords)")
                words = savedWords
                savedWords.removeAll()
                print("savedWords in loadInitialValues in WordsViewController after clear all: \(savedWords)")
            } else {
                saveInitialWordValues(to: defaults)
            }
            chosenLanguageWords.removeAll()
            for word in words {
                let split = word.components(separatedBy: "::")
                if split[7] == chosenLanguage {
                    chosenLanguageWords.append(word)
                }
            }
        }
    }

    func saveInitialWordValues(to defaults: UserDefaults) {
        words.removeAll()
        words.append("Bear::Baissespekulant::0::0::0::0::0::german")
        words.append("Camel::Kamel::0::0::0::0::0::german")
        words.append("Cow::Rind::0::0::0::0::0::german")
        words.append("Fox::Fuchs::0::0::0::0::0::german")
        words.append("Goat::Geiß::0::0::0::0::0::german")
        words.append("Monkey::Affe::0::0::0::0::0::german")
        words.append("Pig::Schwein::0::0::0::0::0::german")
        words.append("Rabbit::Karnickel::0::0::0::0::0::german")
        words.append("Sheep::Schaf::0::0::0::0::0::german")
        words.append("Bear::L'ours::0::0::0::0::0::french")
        words.append("Camel::Le chameau::0::0::0::0::0::french")
        words.append("Cow::La vache::0::0::0::0::0::french")
        words.append("Fox::Le renard::0::0::0::0::0::french")
        words.append("Goat::La chèvre::0::0::0::0::0::french")
        words.append("Monkey::Le singe::0::0::0::0::0::french")
        words.append("Pig::Le cochon::0::0::0::0::0::french")
        words.append("Rabbit::Le lapin::0::0::0::0::0::french")
        words.append("Sheep::Le mouton::0::0::0::0::0::french")
        print("words in saveInitialWordValues in LanguagesViewController are: \(words)")
        print("At end of saveInitialWordValues")

        defaults.set(words, forKey: "words")
    }

    override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
        super.viewWillAppear(animated)

        chosenLanguageLoad()
        navigationItem.title = "\(chosenLanguage.capitalized) Words"
        loadInitialValues()
        tableView.reloadData()
    }

    override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool) {

        navigationController?.setToolbarHidden(true, animated: false)
        super.viewDidAppear(animated)
        chosenLanguageLoad()
        navigationItem.title = "\(chosenLanguage.capitalized) Words"
        loadInitialValues()
        tableView.reloadData()
    }

    override func viewWillDisappear(_ animated: Bool) {
        super.viewWillDisappear(animated)
    }

    @objc func addNewWord() {
        // create our alert controller
        let ac = UIAlertController(title: "Add new word", message: nil, preferredStyle: .alert)

        // add two text fields, one for English and one for foreign word
        ac.addTextField { textField in
            textField.placeholder = "English"
        }

        ac.addTextField { (textField) in
            textField.placeholder = "\(self.chosenLanguage.capitalized)"
        }

        // create an "Add Word" button that submits the user's input
        let submitAction = UIAlertAction(title: "Add Word", style: .default) { [unowned self, ac] (action: UIAlertAction!) in
            // pull out the English and foreign words, or an empty string if there was a problem
            let firstWord = ac.textFields?[0].text?.capitalized ?? ""
            let secondWord = ac.textFields?[1].text?.capitalized ?? ""
            let zeroTimesWrong = "0"
            let homeworkZeroTimesWrong = "0"
            let attemptCount = "0"
            let homeworkAttemptCount = "0"
            let homeworkSet = "0"
            let languageAdded = self.chosenLanguage


            if self.chosenLanguageWords.contains("\(firstWord)") || self.chosenLanguageWords.contains("\(secondWord)") {
                self.wordsExistAlert()
            } else {
                // submit the English and foreign word to the insertFlashcard() method
                self.insertFlashcard(first: firstWord, second: secondWord, third: zeroTimesWrong, fourth: homeworkZeroTimesWrong, fifth: attemptCount, sixth: homeworkAttemptCount, seventh: homeworkSet, eigth: languageAdded)
                self.enableSort()
            }
        }
        // add the submit action, plus a cancel button
        ac.addAction(submitAction)
        ac.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Cancel", style: .cancel))
        // present the alert controller to the user
        present(ac, animated: true)
    }

    func wordsExistAlert() {
        let ac = UIAlertController(title: "Already exists!", message: "Word(s) previously entered!", preferredStyle: .alert)
        let okAction = UIAlertAction(title: "OK", style: .default)
        ac.addAction(okAction)
        self.present(ac, animated: true)
    }

    func insertFlashcard(first: String, second: String, third: String, fourth: String, fifth: String, sixth: String, seventh: String, eigth: String) {
        guard first.count > 0 && second.count > 0 else { return }
    chosenLanguageWords.append("\(first)::\(second)::\(third)::\(fourth)::\(fifth)::\(sixth)::\(seventh)::\(eigth)")
        saveWords()

        let newIndexPath = IndexPath(row: chosenLanguageWords.count - 1, section: 0)
        tableView.insertRows(at: [newIndexPath], with: .automatic)
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, trailingSwipeActionsConfigurationForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UISwipeActionsConfiguration? {
        let delete = UIContextualAction(style: .destructive, title: "Delete") {
            (action, sourceView, completionHandler) in
            self.chosenLanguageWords.remove(at: indexPath.row)
            self.saveWords()
            tableView.beginUpdates()
            tableView.deleteRows(at: [indexPath], with: .left)
            tableView.endUpdates()
            // delete item at indexPath

            self.enableSort()
            completionHandler(true)
        }

        let edit = UIContextualAction(style: .normal, title: "Edit") {
            (action, sourceView, completionHandler) in
            let ac = UIAlertController(title: "Edit word", message: nil, preferredStyle: .alert)

            // add two text fields, one for English and one for foreign word
            ac.addTextField { textField in
                let chosenLanguageWord = self.chosenLanguageWords[indexPath.row]
                let split = chosenLanguageWord.components(separatedBy: "::")
                let englishWord = split[0]
                textField.placeholder = "\(englishWord)"
            }

            ac.addTextField { (textField) in
                let chosenLanguageWord = self.chosenLanguageWords[indexPath.row]
                let split = chosenLanguageWord.components(separatedBy: "::")
                let foreignWord = split[1]
                textField.placeholder = "\(foreignWord)"
            }

            // create an "Edit Word" button that submits the user's input
            let submitAction = UIAlertAction(title: "Edit Word", style: .default) { [unowned self, ac] (action: UIAlertAction!) in
                // pull out the English and foreign words, or an empty string if there was a problem
                let firstWord = ac.textFields?[0].text ?? ""
                let secondWord = ac.textFields?[1].text ?? ""

                guard firstWord.count > 0 && secondWord.count > 0 else { return }
                // edit item at indexPath
                let split = self.chosenLanguageWords[indexPath.row].components(separatedBy: "::")
                let wrongCount = split[2]
                let homeworkWrongCount = split[3]
                let attemptCount = split[4]
                let homeworkAttemptCount = split[5]
                let homeworkSet = split[6]
                let languageEdited = split[7]
                self.chosenLanguageWords.remove(at: indexPath.row)
                self.chosenLanguageWords.insert("\(firstWord)::\(secondWord)::\(wrongCount)::\(homeworkWrongCount)::\(attemptCount)::\(homeworkAttemptCount)\(homeworkSet)::\(languageEdited)", at: indexPath.row)
                self.saveWords()

                tableView.beginUpdates()
                tableView.deleteRows(at: [indexPath], with: .automatic)
                tableView.insertRows(at: [indexPath], with: .automatic)
                tableView.endUpdates()

                /*self.resetEnableDisable()
                self.chosenLanguageLoad()
                self.clearAllEnableDisable()
                self.chosenLanguageLoad()*/
                self.enableSort()
            }

            // add the submit action, plus a cancel button
            ac.addAction(submitAction)
            ac.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Cancel", style: .cancel))

            // present the alert controller to the user
            self.present(ac, animated: true)
            completionHandler(true)
        }

        let homework = UIContextualAction(style: .normal, title: "Homework") {
            (action, sourceView, completionHandler) in
            let chosenLanguageWord = self.chosenLanguageWords[indexPath.row]
            print("words in tableView editActionsForRowAt in WordsViewController are: \(self.words)")

            let split = chosenLanguageWord.components(separatedBy: "::")
            if split[4] == "0" {
                let firstWord = split[0]
                let secondWord = split[1]
                let zeroTimesWrong = split[2]
                let homeworkZeroTimesWrong = split[3]
                let attemptCount = split[4]
                let homeworkAttemptCount = split[5]
                let homeworkSet = "1"
                let language = split[7]

                self.chosenLanguageWords.remove(at: indexPath.row)
            self.chosenLanguageWords.insert("\(firstWord)"+"::"+"\(secondWord)"+"::"+"\(zeroTimesWrong)"+"::"+"\(homeworkZeroTimesWrong)"+"::"+"\(attemptCount)"+"::"+"\(homeworkAttemptCount)"+"::"+"\(homeworkSet)"+"::"+"\(language)", at: indexPath.row)
            } else {
                let firstWord = split[0]
                let secondWord = split[1]
                let zeroTimesWrong = split[2]
                let homeworkZeroTimesWrong = split[3]
                let attemptCount = split[4]
                let homeworkAttemptCount = split[5]
                let homeworkSet = "0"
                let language = split[7]

                self.chosenLanguageWords.remove(at: indexPath.row)

                self.chosenLanguageWords.insert("\(firstWord)"+"::"+"\(secondWord)"+"::"+"\(zeroTimesWrong)"+"::"+"\(homeworkZeroTimesWrong)"+"::"+"\(attemptCount)"+"::"+"\(homeworkAttemptCount)"+"::"+"\(homeworkSet)"+"::"+"\(language)", at: indexPath.row)
            }
            self.saveWords()
            completionHandler(true)
        }

        delete.backgroundColor = UIColor.systemRed
        edit.backgroundColor = UIColor.systemBlue
        homework.backgroundColor = UIColor.systemGreen

        let swipeConfiguration = UISwipeActionsConfiguration(actions: [delete, edit, homework])

        return swipeConfiguration
    }

    func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
        return 1
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        print("number of chosenLanguageWords in tableView(numberOfRowsInSection) are: \(chosenLanguageWords.count)")
        return chosenLanguageWords.count
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        //print("In cellForRowAt function")
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "Word", for: indexPath)

        let chosenLanguageWord = chosenLanguageWords[indexPath.row]

        if chosenLanguageWord != "::" {
            let split = chosenLanguageWord.components(separatedBy: "::")

            print(split[0])

            cell.textLabel?.text = split[0]

            cell.detailTextLabel?.text = ""

            //print(cell)
        }

        return cell
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
        tableView.deselectRow(at: indexPath, animated: true)

        if let cell = tableView.cellForRow(at: indexPath) {
            if cell.detailTextLabel?.text == "" {
                let chosenLanguageWord = chosenLanguageWords[indexPath.row]
                let split = chosenLanguageWord.components(separatedBy: "::")
                cell.detailTextLabel?.text = split[1]
            } else {
                cell.detailTextLabel?.text = ""
            }
        }
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, commit editingStyle: UITableViewCell.EditingStyle, forRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
        chosenLanguageWords.remove(at: indexPath.row)
        saveWords()
        tableView.deleteRows(at: [indexPath], with: .automatic)
    }

    func saveWords() {
        if let defaults = UserDefaults(suiteName: "group.co.uk.tirnaelectronics.hyperpolyglot.todayview") {
            var i = 0
            for word in words {
                print("i in saveWords in WordsViewController is: \(i)")
                let split = word.components(separatedBy: "::")
                if split[7] == chosenLanguage {
                    words.remove(at: i)
                    print("words after remove at index in saveWords in WordsViewController are: \(words)")
                    if i > 0 {
                        i -= 0
                    }
                } else {
                    i += 1
                }
            }
            print("words before append in saveWords in WordsViewController are: \(words)")
            words.append(contentsOf: chosenLanguageWords)
            defaults.set(words, forKey: "words")
            print("words in saveWords after defaults.set in WordsViewController are: \(words)")
        }
    }
}
```

The tableview should load the words associated with the language that is currently chosen. The current language can be changed by the user by tapping the languages button in WordsViewController and selecting a language from the pop over's picker view wheel.

When the done button is tapped in the pop over controller, the pop over disappears and the table view of words should be displayed for the newly chosen language. I don't know how to automatically refresh the table view rows once the pop over disappears. The table view reloads when the user taps a different view controller in the tab bar controller, then taps back on the WordsViewController. It is undesirable to expect the user to have to do this, as the table view should update after the user confirms their change of language.

Answer (score 0):

I recommend you to create a delegate to handle the callback for the language changed, it would be like

```swift
protocol LanguagesPopOverDelegate {
    func choseLanguage(_ language: String)
}
```

Comment: I tried understanding this tutorial: https://medium.com/@jamesrochabrun/implementing-delegates-in-swift-step-by-step-d3211cbac3ef but I cannot successfully implement your suggestion.